# Neo4j: Maintaining node counts

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm investigating the use of Neo4j to detect potentially fraudulent card transactions in near real time.  I receive details of a customer and a card they've just used from our on-line systems.  What I'm trying to do here is create   new nodes for the customer and card if they don't exist, then establish the relationship between them.

Whenever the customer uses the card I want to set the time the card was last used, in addition, if this is the first time this customer-->card relationship has been seen, update totals of the number of cards the customer is associated with and the number of customers associated with the card.

The Cypher below seems to work, however I think it will re-evaluate the counts every time the relationship is seen, not just on the create.  Is it possible to use the ON MATCH and ON CREATE in this statement to limit the unnecessary processing?

```
MERGE (c:customers {customer_id:"12345678"})
MERGE (a:cards {card_hash:"45uIic..."})
MERGE (c)-[r:has_card]->(a)
set r.last_transaction = "30-NOV-2016 07:58:42"
set a.card_ct = size(()-[:has_card]->(a))
set c.card_count = size((c)-[:has_card]->())
```

I'm running this from Python (using py2neo), I also want to return something back that will allow me to kick off a bespoke dijkstra based search of the neighborhood.  Any ideas how I'd return some variable  based on whether this was a new or existing relationship?

Answer (score 3):

There is no need you to even have the `card_ct` or `card_count` properties.

Since neo4j 2.1, getting a count of the number of relationships of a specific type from a node is very efficient. So, every time you need a count, just use `SIZE(()-[:has_card]->(node))` or `SIZE((node)-[:has_card]->())`.

Comment: I'm holding the number of relationships properties on the node so that it's visible in the Neo4j browser, I find it's more useful to see the number of customers associated with a card (or bank, or telephone number...) rather than details such as a hash of a card number.  For the customers, it's useful to have a count of the number of cards etc. they're associated with before trying to expand the node.

Comment: You should not design a data model based on what is easy to visualize in the browser. You should design it to make your actual use cases efficient. You can always perform a query in the browser in the way I suggested, order the results by count, and look at the results in the browser  tabularly or textually.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this. Create a counter on a MATCH and if the counter is greater than zero then it is an existing relationship. Otherwise it is a new relationship.

```
MERGE (c:customers {customer_id:"12345678"})
MERGE (a:cards {card_hash:"45uIic..."})
MERGE (c)-[r:has_card]->(a)
ON MATCH SET r.num = coalesce(r.num, 0) + 1
set r.last_transaction = "30-NOV-2016 07:58:42"
set a.card_ct = size(()-[:has_card]->(a))
set c.card_count = size((c)-[:has_card]->())
RETURN 
CASE 
  WHEN r.num > 0 THEN false
  ELSE true
END as new_relationship
```

Comment: Thanks, that does just what I need.  Also realised that I shouldn't use a new SET on each line, just a using a comma to separate the statements following the ON MATCH will do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Cypher I've ended up with, thanks to Dave Bennett for his suggestion.  I also realised that I don't need to initiate any further analysis if only 1 customer is associated with 1 card so I've excluded this as well.

```
MERGE (c:customers {customer_id:"12345678"})
MERGE (a:cards {card_hash:"BFgn..."})
MERGE (c)-[r:has_card]->(a)
ON CREATE SET a.card_scheme = "VISA DEBIT"
            , a.card_ct = size(()-[:has_card]->(a))
            , c.card_count = size((c)-[:has_card]->())
ON MATCH SET r.ind = 1
SET r.last_transaction = "06-Dec-2016 11:19:13"
RETURN CASE WHEN exists(r.ind) 
                 AND a.card_ct + c.card_count > 2 
                 THEN false 
                 ELSE true END as new_relationship
```